# Scatter chart: distinct color for similar Y value

Tags: google-visualization

For example, let's take this configuration and data:

```js
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Age');
data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');

data.addRows([
    [ 8,      12,       'Female'],
    [ 4,      5.5,      'Unknown'],
    [ 11,     14,       'Female'],
    [ 4,      5,        'Male'],
    [ 3,      3.5,      'Female'],
    [ 6.5,    7,        'Male']
]);
```

What options or column role should I use in order to:

1. have the 'Male', 'Female', and 'Unknown' dots in distinct colors?
2. display the three colors + strings in the legend?

I already managed to achieve [1] with some pre-processing and using "style", but I thought there would be a simpler solution for such a relatively trivial case. Could it be that I missed some point in the documentation?

Comment: Could be interesting to see a working fiddle - you have defined two columns but assigning three data per pair ...?

Comment: Can't find any info about changing sizes and/or colors in a simple way with scatter charts.
I'd recommend you to look at bubble charts instead, [documentation here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#Overview)

Comment: Thank you @HenrikAronsson, I used bubble charts and it worked like a charm!